# Como listar os bancos de dados do sql server em um combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Como listar os bancos de dados do SQL Server em um combobox de uma aplicação C#

Comment: Com relação a como exibir esse dados em um combobox de uma aplicação c#, sua pergunta é muito ampla, primeiro por que não é possível saber se é uma aplicação web ou desktop, segundo por que talvez você está confundindo o propósito do stackoverflow: você deve aprender a exibir informações do banco de dados num combobox em livros, nos infinitos tutoriais que existem na internet, e utilizar o stackoverflow para ser ajudado em eventuais problemas que venha a enfrentar durante o processo de aprendizagem. Ninguém aqui irá fazer seu trabalho por você.

Comment: Bruno, tente fazer as perguntas por partes, você fez uma pergunta de forma muito macro. Onde exatamente você está tendo dificuldades? Já tem uma aplicação que funciona? Como ela é? Onde que empacou?

Comment: Você não consegue nem obter as informações no SQL Server e nem colocar estas informações no *combobox*? São duas coisas diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode conseguir a lista de todos os databases através do comando abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: Peço desculpas meus caros, entrei no stackoverflow hoje e não sabia como realmente funciona e minha pergunta foi abstrata. Consegui resolver na web era muita coisa pra ser respondida em um tópico e o site aqui está aprovado, pelas respostas rápidas e a quantidade de pessoas disponíveis a ajudar.